# Detecting incoming SMS messages

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sms, android-sms

In my android code, I am trying to detect incoming SMS messages. The code below was working since 2 years, but now it stopped working. What updates am I missing?

```
public class SmsListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private String msgBody;
    private SharedPreferences preferences;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        if(intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")){

            Toast.makeText(context,"message received",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();           //---get the SMS message passed in---
            SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
            String msg_from;
            if (bundle != null){
                //---retrieve the SMS message received---
                try{
                    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                    msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                    for(int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                        msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                        msg_from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                        msgBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody();
                        MainActivity.handleMessage(msgBody);
                    }

                    Toast.makeText(context,"message is:"+msgBody,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.d("Exception caught",e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In my Main Activity I am requesting the user permission, and using the SMS receiver as the following:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



//Updated///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
           if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            requestSmsPermission();
        else {
            smsListener = new SmsListener();
            IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
            intentFilter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
            registerReceiver(smsListener, intentFilter);
        }

        ///////Updated///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    }


private void requestSmsPermission() {
    String permission = Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS;
    int grant = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission);
    if ( grant != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        String[] permission_list = new String[1];
        permission_list[0] = permission;
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permission_list, 1);

    }
}

  @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            smsListener = new SmsListener();
            IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
            intentFilter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
            registerReceiver(smsListener, intentFilter);
        }
    }
```

My Manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.zaidalmahmoud.expenseless">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".GraphActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".SmsListener"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity android:name=".DetailedExpenseActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

When the SMS is received, my android application does not detect it, but it does not crash or show anything. Why? Thanks.

**NOTE:** I am not interested in catching SMS with verification code. I want my application to catch any incoming SMS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Android app needs SMS receive/read permission to retrieve SMS content.
Google has introduced SMS Retriever API, this API allows to retrieve the OTP without needing of the SMS permission in your application.

[image]

**Add These Dependency for SMS Retriever API**

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:16.0.0'
```

Then craete an interface like below:

```
public interface OnNewMessageListener {
    void onNewMessageReceived(String activationCode);
}
```

Then, create a broadCastReceiver to catch sms:

```
public class SmsBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    OnNewMessageListener onNewMessageListener;

    public SmsBroadcastReceiver() {
    }

    public SmsBroadcastReceiver(OnNewMessageListener onNewMessageListener) {
        this.onNewMessageListener = onNewMessageListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {
                Status status = (Status) extras.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_STATUS);

                if (status != null)
                    switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                        case CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                            // Get SMS message contents
                            String message = (String) extras.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_SMS_MESSAGE);
                            // Extract one-time code from the message and complete verification
                            // by sending the code back to your server.
                            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(message)) {
                                String activationCode = null;
                                Pattern p = Pattern.compile("your pattern like \\b\\d{4}\\b");
                                Matcher m = p.matcher(message);
                                if (m.find()) {
                                    activationCode = (m.group(0));  // The matched substring
                                }

                                if (onNewMessageListener != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(activationCode))
                                    onNewMessageListener.onNewMessageReceived(activationCode);
                            }
                            break;
                        case CommonStatusCodes.TIMEOUT:
                            // Waiting for SMS timed out (5 minutes)
                            // Handle the error ...
                            break;
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At your `AndroidManifest` declare broadcastReceiver:

```
        <receiver
            android:name=".SmsBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            tools:ignore="ExportedReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.SMS_RETRIEVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Inside your activity add these code:

```
    private SmsBroadcastReceiver smsListener;

     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Get an instance of SmsRetrieverClient, used to start listening for a matching
            // SMS message.
            SmsRetrieverClient client = SmsRetriever.getClient(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()) /* context */);

            // Starts SmsRetriever, which waits for ONE matching SMS message until timeout
            // (5 minutes). The matching SMS message will be sent via a Broadcast Intent with
            // action SmsRetriever#SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION.
            Task<Void> task = client.startSmsRetriever();

            // Listen for success/failure of the start Task. If in a background thread, this
            // can be made blocking using Tasks.await(task, [timeout]);
            task.addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> {
                // Successfully started retriever, expect broadcast intent
                // ...
            });

            task.addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                // Failed to start retriever, inspect Exception for more details
                // ...
            });

            OnNewMessageListener onNewMessageListener = activationCode -> {
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(activationCode)) {
                    editText.setText(String.valueOf(activationCode));
                }
            };
            smsListener = new SmsBroadcastReceiver(onNewMessageListener);
            if (getContext() != null)
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                    getContext().registerReceiver(smsListener, new IntentFilter(SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION));
                }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        try {
            if (getContext() != null && smsListener != null) {
                getContext().unregisterReceiver(smsListener);
                smsListener = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
    }
```

Your sms should be like this:

```
<#> Use 123456 as your verification code 
FC+7qAH5AZu
```

Message must:

- Be no longer than 140 bytes
- Begin with the prefix `<#>`
- Contain a one-time code that the client sends back to your server to complete the verification flow ([see Generating a one-time code](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/verify#generating_a_one-time_code))
- End with an 11-character hash string that identifies your app ([see Computing your app’s hash string](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/verify#computing_your_apps_hash_string))

For more information see this [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview).

**UPDATE**

See this [link](https://android.jlelse.eu/detecting-sending-sms-on-android-8a154562597f).

**EDIT**

Change your activity to this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            requestSmsPermission();
        else {
            smsListener = new SmsListener();
            IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
            intentFilter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
            registerReceiver(smsListener, intentFilter);
        }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
    smsListener= new SmsListener();
    IntentFilter intentFilter=new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
    registerReceiver(smsListener, intentFilter);
    }
}
```

**Update**

Change your `BroadcastReceiver` to this:

```
public class SmsListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private String msgBody;
    private SharedPreferences preferences;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "message received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            try {
                if (bundle != null) {
                    final Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                    for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                        SmsMessage smsMessage;
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                            smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i], bundle.getString("format"));
                        else smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);

                        msg_from = smsMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                        msgBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody();
                        MainActivity.handleMessage(msgBody);
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(context, "message is:" + msgBody, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Exception caught", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I do not want to detect SMS with verification code. My question is about catching any SMS. In fact, I am interested in a totally different kind of SMS.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to reuse some of that code, but I don't see much difference between my code and his code, and I did not get any change in my application. SMS is not detected. I need to know where is my mistake exactly.

Comment: Hi. I would like to tell you that it worked only once, and then it stopped working and I don't know why. I put exactly your code above in the last edit

Comment: @TravelingSalesman I think your problem is at this: MainActivity.handleMessage(msgBody); use an interface to update or send your data to main activity.

Comment: I didn't change anything (except maybe one toast message) and now it is working again. I will keep testing it, and let you know. But I highly doubt there is a problem in MainActivity.handleMessage(msgBody) because I tested it well, or at least because now it is working without having any issue.

Comment: @TravelingSalesman I change something in my answer and update it. Check it again.

Comment: @Masoud Mokhtari I know this is a little bit late to ask but I needed help. I followed your above code and it work, but I want to display the message in an TextView. I tried creating a static string ````message```` in Activity and set it value to ````msgBody```` in ````BroadcastReceiver```` but when I called the ````handleMessage```` in Activity after ````registerReceiver```` but somehow it did not work. It seem no code after ````registerReceiver```` was ran because I put a Log after it but was not shown in debug. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 4):

Declare SMS Read and Receive permission in your android manifest file :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

Then we need a SMS Receiver as follows:

```
class SMSReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent?) {
    if (intent != null && intent.action != null && intent.action!!.equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED", ignoreCase = true)) {
        val bundle = intent.extras
        if (bundle != null) {
            val sms = bundle.get(SMS_BUNDLE) as Array<Any>?
            val smsMsg = StringBuilder()

            var smsMessage: SmsMessage
            if (sms != null) {
                for (sm in sms) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        val format = bundle.getString("format")
                        smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu(sm as ByteArray, format)
                    } else {
                        smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu(sm as ByteArray)
                    }


                    val msgBody = smsMessage.messageBody.toString()
                    val msgAddress = smsMessage.originatingAddress

                    smsMsg.append("SMS from : ").append(msgAddress).append("\n")
                    smsMsg.append(msgBody).append("\n")
                }

                sendBroadcast(smsMsg.toString())
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun sendBroadcast(smsMSG: String) {
    val broadcastIntent = Intent()
    broadcastIntent.action = AppConstants.mBroadcastSMSUpdateAction
    broadcastIntent.putExtra(AppConstants.message, smsMSG)
    EventBus.getDefault().post(EventIntent(broadcastIntent))
}

companion object {

    val SMS_BUNDLE = "pdus"
}
}
```

You can broadcast the received SMS information to your MainActivity.

Then you need to declare the SMS Broadcast receiver in your manifest file as follows:

```
  <receiver
        android:name=".SMSReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

After that on application launch in MainActivity you need to check for SMS permissions by checking:

```
Manifest.permission.READ_SMS,
Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS
```

You can use built in android permission module or RxPermission for that :

```
  val rxPermissions = RxPermissions(this)
    rxPermissions.request(
            Manifest.permission.READ_SMS,
            Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS)
            .subscribe(object : Observer<Boolean> {
                override fun onNext(t: Boolean) {
                    if (t) {

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, getString(R.string.permission_request_denied), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
                }
                override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {}
                override fun onError(e: Throwable) {}
                override fun onComplete() {}
            })
```

Comment: What is this language you are using? That's definitely not java syntax

Comment: @Traveling Salesman That is the new language Kotlin used for Android application development

Comment: Unfortunately I am using Android studio with Java syntax.